# Having issues sending props from a api call into another react component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, frontend, web-component

Ok so I want to make a API call to my GraphQL backend to get an array of campaigns which I want to display on the React frontend in the form of a card. When I make the API call to get all campaigns I get this as a response:

```
{data: {campaigns: [{id: "1", title: "Lucky's Gaming Services",…}]}}
  data: {campaigns: [{id: "1", title: "Lucky's Gaming Services",…}]}
    campaigns: [{id: "1", title: "Lucky's Gaming Services",…}]
     0: {id: "1", title: "Lucky's Gaming Services",…}
       body: "Lucky is opening a gaming service online which allows users to repair gaming 
             consoles"
       campaignType: "FC"
       couponPrice: 5
       couponsCount: 4
       creator: {id: "3", username: "test1", __typename: "UserModel"}
       id: "1"
       slug: "luckygamingservices12"
       title: "Lucky's Gaming Services"
       __typename: "CampaignModel"
```

Currently the campaigns array is just 1 campaign as shown above. Each campaign has attributes such as body, id, title, slug etc.

On my react page, I basically make a call to get this response and then I handle it with this code on the main page:

```
           {loading ? ( <h1>Loading Campaigns...</h1>
            ) : (
              data && data.campaigns.map(campaign => (
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} key={campaign.id}>
              <Card campaign={campaign} multiple={true}/>
              </Grid>
              ) )
            )}
```

Above I pass the campaign into the Card component

On the card component, how do I import the attributes of each campaign such as the body, title, id etc. so i can display that information for each campaign card in the array.

```
export default function Card(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <>
             <Card className={classes.root}>
                        <CardActionArea>
                            <CardMedia
                            className={props.multiple ? classes.mediaMultiple : classes.media}
                            image="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1414235077428-338989a2e8c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9"
                            title="Contemplative Reptile"
                            />
                            </CardActionArea>
                            <CardContent>
                            {props.multiple ? <Box color="#8f8f8f" mb={2} mt={0.5} fontSize={14}>Grund</Box>:
                            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h1">
                                CAMPAIGN TITLE
                            </Typography>}
                            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                                CAMPAIGN BODY
                            </Typography>
                            </CardContent>
                        
                        </Card>
        </>
    )
}
```

Previously it worked when I did this:

```
export default function Card({campaign: {body, id, couponPrice, couponsCount, slug, title, campaignType, creator}}) {
```

I get this ERROR: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined**

How do I pass the attributes/props from the main page into the Card component? It was working fine before but i dont know why not anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're passing `campaign` as a prop and then on your `<Card />` component you are grabbing the `props` as an argument however I don't see anywhere that you are assigning `body` to a variable for use.

You could try iterating over the props by adding the following...

```
const classes = useStyles();
const {body, id, couponPrice, couponsCount, slug, title, campaignType, creator} = props;
```

From there each of those should be saved to a `const` that you can use throughout your `<Card />` component. For instance you should be able to place `{body}` where you want it to appear.

Comment: I just tried that and the error is gone now but the cards don't display the body, title etc. It's just blank

Comment: If you add `console.log(props)` and `console.log(body)` do you get the data you expect?

Comment: console.log(body) = undefined
console.log(props) = {multiple: True}
,
Props doesn't seem to get the campaign object passed from the main page, not sure why

Comment: Maybe I need to spread the props or something like that?

Comment: You could try that, you could also pass in the parts of the campaign as multiple props instead of one big prop. It looks like it's not passing in the `campaign` prop

Comment: I think I got it to work! Thanks for all the help, I don't think I am doing it properly but it seems to be getting me somewhere closer to the solution

Comment: Let me know once you figure it out and if my solution solved then be sure to accept it :)

Comment: Just a follow up, if my answer helped then please mark it as accepted for others that come here looking for the same issue.